# Unable to publish CKEditor Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

After the first version of my plugin was published I had to publish a bug fix for the plugin. 10 hours later the plugin's state was still '(not published)'. As I finished version two of my plugin I decided to upload version 2.0. Same thing here and it is still **not published**.

**What can I do now so my plugin gets published? Thanks for your help!**

The link to my CKEditor plugin is: http://ckeditor.com/addon/imageuploader.
And the link to the plugin's documentation is: http://imageuploaderforckeditor.altervista.org/

Comment: please ask this question on CKEditor forums not this site

Comment: CKEditor forum has been closed and users are redirected to Stack Overflow ;) @Intera Use the email address at the bottom of http://cksource.com/contact and send us your package. We'll investigate what's wrong.

Comment: @WiktorWalc Good morning! I'll send a mail right now. Thanks for the answer!